# Azure ARM Templates - How to pass output variable from linked template as parameters to another template?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Lets say we have 2 linked arm templates with their associated `*.params.json` files:

1. `createAppServiceTemplate.json`
2. `createAppServiceTemplate.params.json`
3. `createSqlDbTemplate.json`
4. `createSqlDbTemplate.params.json`

The second template `createSqlDbTemplate.json` has outputs:

```
 "outputs": {
        "connectionString": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[concat('Database=', parameters('databaseName'), ';Server=', reference(resourceId('Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers',parameters('serverName')), '2017-12-01').fullyQualifiedDomainName, ';User Id=', parameters('administratorLogin'),'@', parameters('serverName'),';Password=', parameters('administratorPassword'))]"
        }
    }
```

I wan't to extract this output variable and pass it as parameter to `createAppServiceTemplate.params.json`.

I have tried to add this to my :

```
"parameters": {
    "usersDbConnectionString": {
          "value": "[reference('createSqlDbTemplate').outputs.connectionString.value]"
    }
 }
```

But I think parameters can't evaluate expressions? How can I achieve the desired behaviour ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you had the linked `createSqlServerTemplate.json` template below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {},
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [],
  "outputs": {
    "greetingMessage": {
      "value": "Hello World",
      "type" : "string"
    }
  }
}
```

The main template deploys the linked template and gets the returned value. Notice that it references the deployment resource by name, and it uses the name of the property returned by the linked template.

`main-template.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {},
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
      "name": "createAppServiceTemplate",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[uri(deployment().properties.templateLink.uri, 'createAppServiceTemplate.json')]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
           "userDbConnectionString: {
              value: "[reference('createSqlServerTemplate').outputs.greetingMessage.value]"
           }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
      "name": "createSqlServerTemplate",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[uri(deployment().properties.templateLink.uri, 'createSqlServerTemplate.json')]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates#get-values-from-linked-template)

Comment: So if I have azuredeploy.json as my `Main` template which has 2 linked templates. In order to pass data between those 2 linked templates i need to extract it to the main first and then pass it as parameters?

Comment: In your main template, you provide a name for the linked template, this is under "linkedTemplate" in the example above. You can see in the top sample you define the outputs and then just reference them. So, if you had a `Main` template, then an output defined as `sqlResourceId` then you'd reference it as... `[reference('BuildSql').outputs.sqlResourceId]` providing your template was referenced using a linked template named `BuildSql`

Comment: I have suggested an edit in order to clarify things a bit. I am not 100% sure if using that `value: [reference...` would work?

Comment: Should do, you can pass parameters when linking templates... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates#parameters-for-linked-template

Comment: Excellent, and I imagine this would not be possible if we used `parametersLink` instead of `parameters` ?